# Having trouble with my page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of setting up my wordpress site, I finished converting the html to php files but I'm getting this error code:

> syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in *my website url*/page.php
>   on line 2

This is my 1st and 2nd line, do you have any idea what i'm suppose to change? Sorry if this is all over the place this is my first time coding anything lol.

```
<? php
echo '<div class="slicknav_menu"><div class="slicknav_brand"><a 
href="https://twitter.com/pipdig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><i 
class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://instagram.com/pipdig" 
target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a><a 
href="https://www.facebook.com/pipdig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow 
noopener"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a 
href="https://www.pinterest.com/pipdig/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow 
noopener"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></div><a href="#" aria- 
haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" class="slicknav_btn 
slicknav_collapsed"><span class="slicknav_menutxt"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
</span><span class="slicknav_icon"><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"> 
</span></span></a><ul role="menu" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" 
class="slicknav_nav slicknav_hidden"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type- 
post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-128"><a tabindex="-1" 
role="menuitem" href="../../about/index.html">About</a></li>';
```

Comment: change <? php to <?php

Comment: It should be `<?php` not `<? php`

Comment: @joshuamabina 4 seconds  :-)

Comment: Yeah @Tom, 4 seconds :-)

Comment: I'm also not sure why your using a PHP tag and then echoing out a load of HTML.  You would be better off just using the HTML and laying it out to make it a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @NigelRen "first time coding anything"

Comment: @Tom which is why I pointed it out, better to highlight different ways of doing  things now rather than in a few months time.

Comment: @NigelRen "I'm also not sure why" .. that's why.

Answer (score 0):

do following

```
<?php ?>

<div class="slicknav_menu"><div class="slicknav_brand"><a 
href="https://twitter.com/pipdig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><i 
class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://instagram.com/pipdig" 
target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a><a 
href="https://www.facebook.com/pipdig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow 
noopener"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a 
href="https://www.pinterest.com/pipdig/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow 
noopener"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></div><a href="#" aria- 
haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" class="slicknav_btn 
slicknav_collapsed"><span class="slicknav_menutxt"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
</span><span class="slicknav_icon"><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"> 
</span></span></a><ul role="menu" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" 
class="slicknav_nav slicknav_hidden"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type- 
post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-128"><a tabindex="-1" 
role="menuitem" href="../../about/index.html">About</a></li>
<?php
```

What I have done above is exit the php mode, then use html, then enter into php mode again to do the PHP functions etc..